# URLFOR and a parameter name which starts with a digit

Tags: apex

I'm having trouble with a `commandButton` which uses the `URLFOR` function and wonder if what I am attempting to do is possible or if I should approach the problem in another way.

I have this markup, where `TaskType` is the name of an `<apex:attribute />`:

```
<apex:commandButton value="New" 
    action="{!URLFOR($Action.Task.NewTask, null, [00No0000006UApM = TaskType])}" />
```

The Task object in this org has a custom picklist field on it, which has the noted field id and that is also the element name in the Task page. When I build a URL by hand with this parameter name and a value, it works great and the field value is set correctly via the URL param.

However, when I attempt to use the parameters array in the URLFOR function and the parameter name begins with anything other than an alpha-character the compilation fails with the error message:

> Compilation error: Syntax error.  Found '['

If I change the name of the param to start with an alpha instead of a digit, it saves fine... but then the name of the parameter is incorrect and nothing works.

Must I build the URL manually?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to modify your code.

Currently you are using this code:

```
<apex:commandButton value="New" 
    action="{!URLFOR($Action.Task.NewTask, null, [00No0000006UApM = TaskType])}" />
```

You need to use this code:

```
<apex:commandButton value="New" action="{!URLFOR($Action.Task.NewTask, null, ['00No0000006UApM' = TaskType])}" />
```

You need to add **'** for your parameters as you are not using any variable.

Please try this code and let me know if you face any issue.

Comment: You're correct. Adding the single quotes solved the problem. I had added the quotes and attempted to save multiple times myself because, of course, it should have worked. Yet I still received a syntax error. So instead I rewrote it to use a controller method rather than URLFOR. After that success, the single quotes implementation saved without error. I loathe the Salesforce compiler at times. Thanks for the assistance.